# teamviewer crash at startup

Tags: crash, autostart, teamviewer

Every time I powerup my Ubuntu 14.04 laptop I get a "system program program detected" message.
The reporting window shows that the info comes from the apport-gtk-root system, that as far as I know is the crash reporting system.
Looking into the /var/crash folder I find this file:
_opt_teamviewer_tv_bin_teamviewerd.0.crash
Seems that teamviewer starts by itself and crashes.
My question is double:
**- why does teamviewer unnderground process start?** I've been looking into autostart folders:
/home/salvatore/.config/autostart
/usr/share/autostart
but didn't find any teamviewer entry
**- why does teamviewer start?**
Below the crash information with no memory dump.
Thanks for help.

```
problemType: Crash
Architecture: amd64
CrashCounter: 1
Date: Wed Mar  2 09:32:10 2016
DistroRelease: Ubuntu 14.04
ExecutablePath: /opt/teamviewer/tv_bin/teamviewerd
ExecutableTimestamp: 1415026666
ProcCmdline: /opt/teamviewer/tv_bin/teamviewerd -f
ProcCwd: /opt/teamviewer
ProcEnviron:
 PATH=(custom, no user)
 TERM=linux
ProcMaps:
 08048000-087ed000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1710244                            /opt/teamviewer/tv_bin/teamviewerd
 087ed000-087f1000 r-xp 007a4000 08:01 1710244                            /opt/teamviewer/tv_bin/teamviewerd
 087f1000-087f2000 rwxp 007a8000 08:01 1710244                            /opt/teamviewer/tv_bin/teamviewerd
 087f2000-08801000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
 08906000-089cc000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
 ee9fe000-ee9ff000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
 ee9ff000-ef1ff000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0                                  [stack:11728]
 ef1ff000-ef200000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
 ef200000-efa00000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0                                  [stack:1330]
 efa00000-efa21000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
 efa21000-efb00000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
 efb00000-efb21000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
 efb21000-efc00000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
 efc00000-efc21000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
 efc21000-efd00000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
 efd00000-efd21000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
 efd21000-efe00000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
 efe00000-efe21000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
 efe21000-eff00000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
 efffb000-efffc000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
 efffc000-f07fc000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0                                  [stack:1329]
 f07fc000-f07fd000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
 f07fd000-f0ffd000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0                                  [stack:1328]
 f0ffd000-f0ffe000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
 f0ffe000-f17fe000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0                                  [stack:1327]
 f17fe000-f17ff000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
 f17ff000-f1fff000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0                                  [stack:1326]
 f1fff000-f2000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
 f2000000-f2800000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0                                  [stack:1325]
 f2800000-f2821000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
 f2821000-f2900000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
 f29ff000-f2a00000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
 f2a00000-f3200000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0                                  [stack:1324]
 f3200000-f3221000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
 f3221000-f3300000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
 f3302000-f331e000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 800039                             /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
 f331e000-f331f000 rwxp 0001b000 08:01 800039                             /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
 f331f000-f3332000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 799640                             /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libresolv-2.19.so
 f3332000-f3333000 ---p 00013000 08:01 799640                             /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libresolv-2.19.so
 f3333000-f3334000 r-xp 00013000 08:01 799640                             /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libresolv-2.19.so
 f3334000-f3335000 rwxp 00014000 08:01 799640                             /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libresolv-2.19.so
 f3335000-f3337000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
 f3337000-f3342000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 799643                             /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.19.so
 f3342000-f3343000 r-xp 0000a000 08:01 799643                             /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.19.so
 f3343000-f3344000 rwxp 0000b000 08:01 799643                             /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.19.so
 f3344000-f3359000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 799649                             /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnsl-2.19.so
 f3359000-f335a000 r-xp 00015000 08:01 799649                             /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnsl-2.19.so
 f335a000-f335b000 rwxp 00016000 08:01 799649                             /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnsl-2.19.so
 f335b000-f335d000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
 f337f000-f3380000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
 f3380000-f3b80000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0                                  [stack:1323]
 f3b80000-f3b81000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
 f3b81000-f4381000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0                                  [stack:1322]
 f4381000-f4382000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
 f4382000-f4b82000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0                                  [stack:1321]
 f4b82000-f4b83000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
 f4b83000-f5383000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0                                  [stack:1320]
 f5383000-f5384000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
 f5384000-f5b84000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0                                  [stack:1319]
 f5b84000-f5b85000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
 f5b85000-f6385000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0                                  [stack:1318]
 f6385000-f6386000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
 f6386000-f6b86000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0                                  [stack:1317]
 f6b86000-f6b87000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
 f6b87000-f7389000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0                                  [stack:1316]
 f7389000-f738e000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 794999                             /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6.0.0
 f738e000-f738f000 r-xp 00004000 08:01 794999                             /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6.0.0
 f738f000-f7390000 rwxp 00005000 08:01 794999                             /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6.0.0
 f7390000-f7393000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 799638                             /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdl-2.19.so
 f7393000-f7394000 r-xp 00002000 08:01 799638                             /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdl-2.19.so
 f7394000-f7395000 rwxp 00003000 08:01 799638                             /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdl-2.19.so
 f7395000-f7396000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
 f7396000-f73b6000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 795006                             /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1.1.0
 f73b6000-f73b7000 r-xp 0001f000 08:01 795006                             /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1.1.0
 f73b7000-f73b8000 rwxp 00020000 08:01 795006                             /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1.1.0
 f73b8000-f7560000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 799641                             /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.19.so
 f7560000-f7562000 r-xp 001a8000 08:01 799641                             /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.19.so
 f7562000-f7563000 rwxp 001aa000 08:01 799641                             /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.19.so
 f7563000-f7566000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
 f7566000-f75aa000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 786571                             /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm-2.19.so
 f75aa000-f75ab000 r-xp 00043000 08:01 786571                             /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm-2.19.so
 f75ab000-f75ac000 rwxp 00044000 08:01 786571                             /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm-2.19.so
 f75ac000-f76dc000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 795013                             /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6.3.0
 f76dc000-f76dd000 r-xp 00130000 08:01 795013                             /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6.3.0
 f76dd000-f76df000 rwxp 00131000 08:01 795013                             /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6.3.0
 f76df000-f76e0000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
 f76e0000-f76e2000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 794993                             /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6.0.0
 f76e2000-f76e3000 r-xp 00001000 08:01 794993                             /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6.0.0
 f76e3000-f76e4000 rwxp 00002000 08:01 794993                             /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6.0.0
 f76e4000-f76e5000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
 f76e5000-f76ec000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 799642                             /lib/i386-linux-gnu/librt-2.19.so
 f76ec000-f76ed000 r-xp 00006000 08:01 799642                             /lib/i386-linux-gnu/librt-2.19.so
 f76ed000-f76ee000 rwxp 00007000 08:01 799642                             /lib/i386-linux-gnu/librt-2.19.so
 f76ee000-f7706000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 793476                             /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.19.so
 f7706000-f7707000 r-xp 00018000 08:01 793476                             /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.19.so
 f7707000-f7708000 rwxp 00019000 08:01 793476                             /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.19.so
 f7708000-f770a000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
 f770e000-f7713000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 793468                             /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnss_dns-2.19.so
 f7713000-f7714000 r-xp 00004000 08:01 793468                             /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnss_dns-2.19.so
 f7714000-f7715000 rwxp 00005000 08:01 793468                             /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnss_dns-2.19.so
 f7715000-f771f000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 799637                             /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnss_nis-2.19.so
 f771f000-f7720000 r-xp 00009000 08:01 799637                             /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnss_nis-2.19.so
 f7720000-f7721000 rwxp 0000a000 08:01 799637                             /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnss_nis-2.19.so
 f7721000-f7728000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 793467                             /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnss_compat-2.19.so
 f7728000-f7729000 r-xp 00006000 08:01 793467                             /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnss_compat-2.19.so
 f7729000-f772a000 rwxp 00007000 08:01 793467                             /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnss_compat-2.19.so
 f772a000-f772e000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
 f772e000-f772f000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                                  [vdso]
 f772f000-f774f000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 799644                             /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.19.so
 f774f000-f7750000 r-xp 0001f000 08:01 799644                             /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.19.so
 f7750000-f7751000 rwxp 00020000 08:01 799644                             /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.19.so
 ffa1e000-ffa3f000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0                                  [stack]
ProcStatus:
 Name:  teamviewerd
 State: D (disk sleep)
 Tgid:  1240
 Ngid:  0
 Pid:   1240
 PPid:  1
 TracerPid: 0
 Uid:   0   0   0   0
 Gid:   0   0   0   0
 FDSize:    64
 Groups:    0 
 VmPeak:      151504 kB
 VmSize:      151368 kB
 VmLck:        0 kB
 VmPin:        0 kB
 VmHWM:    12232 kB
 VmRSS:    12232 kB
 VmData:      139232 kB
 VmStk:      136 kB
 VmExe:     7828 kB
 VmLib:     4092 kB
 VmPTE:      312 kB
 VmSwap:           0 kB
 Threads:   17
 SigQ:  0/63171
 SigPnd:    0000000000000000
 ShdPnd:    0000000000000000
 SigBlk:    0000000000000000
 SigIgn:    0000000000000000
 SigCgt:    00000001800152af
 CapInh:    0000000000000000
 CapPrm:    0000001fffffffff
 CapEff:    0000001fffffffff
 CapBnd:    0000001fffffffff
 Seccomp:   0
 Cpus_allowed:  ff
 Cpus_allowed_list: 0-7
 Mems_allowed:  00000000,00000001
 Mems_allowed_list: 0
 voluntary_ctxt_switches:   11700
 nonvoluntary_ctxt_switches:    38
Signal: 11
Uname: Linux 3.13.0-44-generic x86_64
UserGroups:
```